# How to access system resources in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, google-chrome-app, ppapi

I am developing a chrome extension which needs to fetch some configuration from a system file... Earlier chrome provided NPAPI plug-ins, which could access any system resource (win registry, file system, IPC calls etc...)

However knowing that NPAPI will be discontinued soon, i am looking for alternatives.. one of the ways to build a plug-in is using Pepper clients, but pepper clients read/write only to chrome local storage.. which looks like a more data version of cookies...

So is there any other alternative to access system resources (like registry, files etc) in chrome extensions now??

Comment: [This thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebreath-dev/gqgrUg5orwk/vWvglxBCMlgJ) might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested alternative to NPAPI for many cases is "Native Messaging", where you provide an installer to users which adds binary code that chrome can communicate with via message passing. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging.

For file access, in packaged apps there is the fileSystem API that lets you get access to the actual (non-sandboxed) filesystem. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html.